# JavaScript to calculate Age based on date

Tags: javascript, date

Currently am using JavaScript code to calculate age based on date of birth given by user, its working good but the age showing is wrong.

mycode :

```
function getAge(dateString) {
  var now = new Date();
  var today = new Date(now.getYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate());

  var yearNow = now.getYear();
  var monthNow = now.getMonth();
  var dateNow = now.getDate();

  var dob = new Date(dateString.substring(6,10),
                     dateString.substring(0,2)-1,                   
                     dateString.substring(3,5)                  
                     );

  var yearDob = dob.getYear();
  var monthDob = dob.getMonth();
  var dateDob = dob.getDate();
  var age = {};
  var ageString = "";
  var yearString = "";
  var monthString = "";
  var dayString = "";


  yearAge = yearNow - yearDob;

  if (monthNow >= monthDob)
    var monthAge = monthNow - monthDob;
  else {
    yearAge--;
    var monthAge = 12 + monthNow -monthDob;
  }

  if (dateNow >= dateDob)
    var dateAge = dateNow - dateDob;
  else {
    monthAge--;
    var dateAge = 31 + dateNow - dateDob;

    if (monthAge < 0) {
      monthAge = 11;
      yearAge--;
    }
  }

  age = {
      years: yearAge,
      months: monthAge,
      days: dateAge
      };

  if ( age.years > 1 ) yearString = " years";
  else yearString = " year";
  if ( age.months> 1 ) monthString = " months";
  else monthString = " month";
  if ( age.days > 1 ) dayString = " days";
  else dayString = " day";


  if ( (age.years > 0) && (age.months > 0) && (age.days > 0) )
    ageString = age.years + yearString + ", " + age.months + monthString + ", and " + age.days + dayString + " old.";
  else if ( (age.years == 0) && (age.months == 0) && (age.days > 0) )
    ageString = "Only " + age.days + dayString + " old!";
  else if ( (age.years > 0) && (age.months == 0) && (age.days == 0) )
    ageString = age.years + yearString + " old. Happy Birthday!!";
  else if ( (age.years > 0) && (age.months > 0) && (age.days == 0) )
    ageString = age.years + yearString + " and " + age.months + monthString + " old.";
  else if ( (age.years == 0) && (age.months > 0) && (age.days > 0) )
    ageString = age.months + monthString + " and " + age.days + dayString + " old.";
  else if ( (age.years > 0) && (age.months == 0) && (age.days > 0) )
    ageString = age.years + yearString + " and " + age.days + dayString + " old.";
  else if ( (age.years == 0) && (age.months > 0) && (age.days == 0) )
    ageString = age.months + monthString + " old.";
  else ageString = "Oops! Could not calculate age!";

  return ageString;
}
$(".date").on("change", function(){
var dob = $('.date').val();
 var age = getAge(dob); 
 $('.age').val(age);
});
```

Here is link of jsfiddle [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ursdineshr/bzavye3L/1/)

If i give a date 21/03/1993 am getting age as 20, but the correct age is 23

Comment: I have added an answer check it out.

Comment: If someone was born on 21st March 1993 they'd be 22 not 23.

Comment: try to use moment.js library.It really helpful.All if/else are considered in date difference calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The date order is mm/dd/yyyy or yyyy/mm/dd

So, Change you code to :

```
 var dob = new Date(dateString.substring(6,10),
                     dateString.substring(3,5),                   
                     dateString.substring(0,2)-1                  
                     );
```

**Important Suggestion:**

In javascript date object, month starts from `0`, so your calculation is wrong.

Change code to:

```
if (monthNow >= monthDob)
  var monthAge = monthNow - monthDob + 1;  //<== add one here
  else {
    yearAge--;
    var monthAge = 12 + monthNow -monthDob;
  }
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzavye3L/4/)

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I have to anything with dates in Javascript I tend to lean towards using [Moment JS](http://momentjs.com). This makes what you're trying to do so much simpler.

```
function age(birthDateString){
    var now = moment();
    var birthDate = moment('21/03/1993','DD/MM/YYYY');
    var yearDiff = moment.duration(now - birthDateString).as('years');
    return Math.floor(yearDiff);
}
```

Done - `age('21/03/1993')` returns `22`

Answer (score 0):

Your input format is wrong. Try 03.21.1993.

Comment: I think what @patricmj means is that Javascript Dates follow the American date format (MM/DD/YYYY), unlike many other parts of the world, where it's (DD/MM/YYYY)

Comment: The default format that JavaScript dates use depends on the locale of the computer the JavaScript is running on. Try to stick to ISO8601 strings when representing time when possible